# Is "beauty king" or "handsome king" the counterpart of "beauty queen"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

"**beauty queen**" is a woman who won a beauty contest.

What is the general term for a man who wins a male "handsome" contest?

Is "**beauty king**" or "**handsome king**" the counterpart of "**beauty queen**"?

Comment: This is part of the cultural distinction between men and women. In America and other English-speaking cultures, there are usually female beauty contests, but there are not corresponding male beauty contests. If there were, there would be few contestants, I suspect -- display of "beauty" is not a male characteristic in these cultures. The words we use are different for males, who are _handsome_, and females, who are _beautiful_ and _pretty_. Spanish does well with _guapo/guapa_, but English has to have different words. It's an insult to call a young boy "pretty" in the US.

Comment: There's a term/title for bodybuilders: Mr. Universe.

Comment: There are "beauty" competitions for men, they're usually called Mr and the name of the country in which they are participating. For example; [Mr. United States](http://www.mrunitedstates.org/) and [Mr Italia](https://www.agorainforma.it/nicola-savarese-il-piu-bello-ditalia-si-racconta/) Ah, let's not forget People's magazine's [**Sexiest Man Alive**](https://people.com/movies/paul-rudd-people-sexiest-man-alive-2021/) and then there's [Prom King](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prom-king)

Answer (score 1):

The is no *general* term for a man who wins a male "handsome" contest for the simple reason that such contests do not generally exist.

I would not be surprised if some such contests exist (and I make no judgements about that) but they are far from common enough to have gained a place in the general public consciousness, or for any terminology associated with them to have become "general".

Answer (score 0):

> "Mister" can also be used in combination with another word to refer to someone who is regarded as the personification of, or master of, a particular field or subject, especially in the fields of popular entertainment and sports. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr.)

In this case beauty ^.

> There are "beauty" competitions for men, they're usually called Mr and the name of the country in which they are participating. For example; [Mr. United States](http://www.mrunitedstates.org/) and [Mr Italia](https://www.agorainforma.it/nicola-savarese-il-piu-bello-ditalia-si-racconta/) - @Mari-Lou A

Comment: I would disagree with the analogies with "sexiest man alive" and "prom king". The female recipients of the corresponding honors are not called "beauty queens", and the kinds of "contests" that are involved are usually quite different.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan changed accordingly